# How to set the date of other servers to be the same as the current server's?

Tags: linux, datetime, set

I would like to set the date time of some VM servers to be the same date time as the hosting server so that I can have a synchronized time for running the 'at' job in linux. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run an NTP daemon on your host server, and configure the guest VMs to use the host as an NTP time source?

Comment: Thanks hircus. I am quite new in doing this linux admin works. Do you have some good and reliable resources for setting up NTP? (I don't want to stuff up our servers my testing things suggesting on the web)

Comment: What Linux distribution and version is running on the hosting server?

Comment: This is the output from 'uname -a': Linux fujin 2.6.32-27-server #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 02:05:21 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: ah. For Ubuntu, this might help -- http://www.ubuntugeek.com/network-time-protocol-ntp-server-and-clients-setup-in-ubuntu.html